# zsh: command not found: express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I installed node and npm and both work fine.

However, when I try to install express via `npm install -g express` I get:

zsh: command not found: express.

I Have tried adding various paths in my `.zshrc` file with no luck.

If I echo `$path` I get this:

```
Users/Adam/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin /usr/local/heroku/bin /Users/Adam/.rbenv/shims /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

If i run `npm - prefix -g` i get this:

```
npm@1.4.3 /Users/Adam/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Using mac osx 10 with zsh.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

it seems that you need to install express-generator too

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

take a look at: http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

or: [Express command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found)