# CSS is not loading in easyrtc application on node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, easyrtc

I've some css issues in my easyrtc application, Here is my physical file structure

- project

  - login

    - css

      - style.css
    - js

      - script.css
    - login.html
    - logout.html
  - node_modules
  - static

    - server.js
    - package.json

In the server.js I've defined,

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.redirect('/login');
});
```

and

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
 res.sendfile('login.html', {root: './login'});
});
```

In my login.html I've include following link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
```

Also I've tried with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./login/css/login.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
```

But this css file is not loading to browser, I've inspect the element. But there was an empty css file in sources.
How can I fix this? What is the root of localhost:8080 my webserver running in port 8080
Although I go through the [this nodejs express solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253879/nodejs-express-css-and-js-not-loaded) but I'm afraid can use this kind of solution for my existing project. If yes how can I add express middle-ware to load css?
Help in advance. May the FOSS be with you.

Comment: your route terminator is just `function(req,res)`, no `next` argument since you won't be moving on to a next middleware call. That said, how are you exposing the CSS? Do you have the `login` dir marked as static so that all its content is web-visible? If not, no URL is going to ever get to it without an `app.get(...)`  dedicated to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual server.js used with easyrtc (as supplied in the server_example directory) has a directory called **static** that serves as the root directory of the static files getting served. For example, if you put files called `xxx.html` and `yyy.css` in the static folder, you could reference xxx as

> ```
>   http://yoursite.com/xxx.html
> ```

and inside xxx.html you could reference yyy.css in your link statements as

> href="yyy.css"

or

> href="/yyy.css"

Needless to say, subdirectories work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eric I've put those file in static directory and it's work. But You gave the answer with reasons. Thanks again...